# API to programmatically determine which wordpress plugins are out of date

Tags: plugins, api, linux

Is there an API or an automated way to determine which plugins are out of date and/or have newer versions?

I have about 10 different linux servers, and each server has at least 5 installations of wordpress. I do not want to login to each 50+ wordpress one at a time to manually inspect which site has out of date plugins.

I would like to write a small little bash script or php script that can automatically scan each wordpress installation for which plugins are out of date, and ship that information to my SIEM platform where I can quickly review everything on a daily basis.

Comment: You can use [`get_plugin_updates()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_plugin_updates/) to get a list of plugins that need updates (at least from the WP plugin repository). You could [add a new REST API route](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_rest_route/) to deliver that data (you would probably want to restrict access to the route so the whole world can't see what plugins need updates).

Comment: Have you tried WP CLI? https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/plugin/list/

Comment: I would never normally just recommend a third party service, but honestly, check out https://managewp.com - you can, for free, connect all of those WP sites to ManageWP and then you just log in to their platform every morning and get a full overview of what's going on.  Plugin and Theme monitoring & updates are a free service, as are weekly back-ups.  There are paid add-ons, but they're cheap and can be enabled on a site-by-site basis. You also don't have to enable any of them and can just use the free features as long as you like. (By cheap, we're talking $1 per feature enabled, per site.)